# como evitar en Windows 10 los mensaje de permiso denegado al hacer búsquedas con find en gitbash

Tags: windows10, busqueda, git-bash

Estoy utilizando GitBash como consola en Windows 10 y lo que quiero hacer es evitar que me desplieguen los mensajes de error como "**Permission denied**" al ejecutar un comando find como

```
find /c/. -type f -regex ".*Des*.txt" | xargs grep "Pepito"
```

he intentado usando **2>/dev/null** pero no me resuelve el problema, me sigue desplegando el mensaje.

*find: ‘/c/./$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-2160759231-3699602832-2136691592-1003’: Permission denied*

alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que tal ejecutando git bash como administrador?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, **si ejecutas GIT BASH como administrador en Windows, actuará como si fueras 'root'**.

De otro modo, puedes instalar 'win-sudo' para habilitar el comando 'sudo' en GIT  BASH (ya que como emulador, no trae previamente integrada esa opción).

Para instalar 'win-sudo' necesitas tener previamente NodeJs instalado.
Ejecuta:

```
npm install -g win-sudo
```

y ya puedes usar sudo antepuesto a cualquier comando desde tu emulador GIT BASH, o iniciar con la llamad a 'su' para dejar la sesión completa en modo 'root'

Es decir:

```
su
find /c/. -type f -regex ".*Des*.txt" | xargs grep "Pepito"
```

ó

```
sudo find /c/. -type f -regex ".*Des*.txt" | xargs grep "Pepito"
```